# Alert Service in angular 2

Tags: angular

Below is how i am implementing alert services in my tutorial application but it is not working. What could be the problem please? None of the alert messages both on the login page and the registration page is working

**login component**

```
login(){
    this.authenticateLoginService.login(this.login.email, this.login.password)
       .subscribe(data => {
          this.redirectToLoginPage();
       },
       error => {
          this.alertService.error('Invalid Username or Password');
          this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

**registration page**

```
Register(){
   this.httpService.createUser(this.module)
      .subscribe(data => {
         this.alertService.success('Registration Successful', true);
         this.redirectToLoginPage()
         console.log(data);
       },
       error =>{
         this.alertService.error(error);
       });
}
```

**alert service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    private keepAfterNavigationChange = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
       // clear alert message on route change
       router.events.subscribe(event => {
       if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (this.keepAfterNavigationChange) {
              // only keep for a single location change
              this.keepAfterNavigationChange = false;
          } else {
              // clear alert
              this.subject.next();
          }
       }
   });
   }

   success(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
       this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
       this.subject.next({ type: 'success', text: message });
   }

   error(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = false) {
        this.keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
        this.subject.next({ type: 'error', text: message });
   }

   getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
   }
 }
```

**alert.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { AlertService } from '../Services/alert_services';

 @Component({
    selector: 'alert',
    templateUrl: 'alert.html'
 })

 export class AlertComponent {
   message: any;

   constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
   }
 }
```

**alert.html**

```
 <div *ngIf="message" [ngClass]="{ 'alert': message, 'alert-success': message.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': message.type === 'error' }">{{message.text}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add  in your app.component.html like this
`<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <alert></alert>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>`

Comment: Hello akiv , same thing i did , but still not working.subject.next not firing ngonint ..so alert not updating .

Comment: If I want too show under the login button in login htmlm then what to do @Akiv ?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check the logic of your code, but one obvious thing is that I don't see you provide AlertService.
So you have the choice to provide in AppModule or in every component where you use the service. For example :

```
            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

            import { AlertService } from '../Services/alert_services';

            @Component({
                selector: 'alert',
                templateUrl: 'alert.html',
                providers: [AlertService], //add this line
            })

            export class AlertComponent 

           {
            message: any;

            constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }

            ngOnInit() {
                this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {         this.message = message; });
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok, then could you share with us the error you are getting when you open your browser console ?